# Want PostgreSQL query for replacing string after 3rd character upto specific symbol

Tags: database, postgresql

I am writing a query to replace all email with select query, after 3rd character string should be replaced with `******` upto `@` symbol and rest would be as it is.

For eg.

Input:

```
abcdefghijk@gmail.com
```

Output:

```
abc*****@gmail.com
```

I tried:

```
select REGEXP_REPLACE(email, '(.{3})(?!$)', '\1*****') from user
```

but this give me output:

```
abc*****defghijk@gmail.com
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
select replace('abcdefghijk@gmail.com',substring('abcdefghijk@gmail.com',4,strpos('abcdefghijk@gmail.com','@')-4),'*****') 
union
select replace('xyzabc@aol.com',substring('xyzabc@aol.com',4,strpos('xyzabc@aol.com','@')-4),'*****')
union
select replace('johnnik@icloud.com',substring('johnnik@icloud.com',4,strpos('johnnik@icloud.com','@')-4),'*****');
```

**Edit**: After getting comment, the query is changed to:

```
select replace('test@gmail.com',substring('test@gmail.com',4,strpos('test@gmail.com','@')-3),'*****@');
```

Comment: Tried your query, select replace('test@gmail.com',substring('test@gmail.com',4,strpos('test@gmail.com','@')-4),'*****')
Output: *****es*****@gmail.com

Comment: Ah!, how about this one: `select replace('test@gmail.com',substring('test@gmail.com',4,strpos('test@gmail.com','@')-3),'*****@');` ?

Comment: Worked like gem. Thank you!